# How is it possible for gdb to detect more entries than exits in a function?

Tags: c++, gdb

I'm currently working on this piece of code :

```
16 functionResult function::applyfunction(const molecule m[2])const{
// \func compute the results of the application of the function on m
 17         functionResult fr;
 18         if (this->inst()==assemble){
 19                 fr.cut=false;
 20                 fr.del[0]=m[0];
 21                 fr.del[1]=m[1];
 22                 fr.add[0]=(this->id==0)? m[1]+m[0] : m[0]+m[1];
 23                 }
 24         else{
 25                 std::pair<molecule,molecule> p;
 26                 p=m[0].split(this->id-2);
 27                 fr.cut=true;
 28                 fr.del[0] = m[0];
 29                 fr.add[0] = p.first;
 30                 fr.add[1] = p.second;
 31                 }       
 32         return fr;
 33         }
```

Using gdb debugger, I've set two breakpoints as below :

```
(gdb) break function.cpp:17
Breakpoint 1 at 0x7324: file function.cpp, line 17.
(gdb) break function.cpp:32
Breakpoint 2 at 0x741b: file function.cpp, line 32.
(gdb) ignore 1 10000
Will ignore next 10000 crossings of breakpoint 1.
(gdb) ignore 2 10000
Will ignore next 10000 crossings of breakpoint 2.
```

**Problem :**
When I run the program, it stops for some reason but that is not why I'm posting here. The reason why I'mposting is that when the program stops, I look out for the breakpoints :

```
(gdb) info break 1
Num     Type           Disp Enb Address            What
1       breakpoint     keep y   0x000055555555b324 in function::applyfunction(molecule const*) const at function.cpp:17
    breakpoint already hit 326 times
    ignore next 9674 hits
(gdb) info break 2
Num     Type           Disp Enb Address            What
2       breakpoint     keep y   0x000055555555b41b in function::applyfunction(molecule const*) const at function.cpp:32
    breakpoint already hit 261 times
    ignore next 9739 hits
```

So, how is it possible for my program to enters multiple more times in a function than it exits? I precise that my whole program is one-thread-only.

*edit :* I've compiled to get assembly code with `gcc -S -fverbose-asm function.cpp` and I get :

```
  1 # function.cpp:16: functionResult function::applyfunction(const molecule m[2])const{    // \func compute the results of th    e application of the function on m
  2         movq    %fs:40, %rax    #, tmp141
  3         movq    %rax, -24(%rbp) # tmp141, D.69134
  4         xorl    %eax, %eax      # tmp141
  5 # function.cpp:17:      functionResult fr;
  6         movq    -168(%rbp), %rax        # <retval>, tmp102
  7         movq    %rax, %rdi      # tmp102,
  8         call    _ZN14functionResultC1Ev #
  9 # function.cpp:18:      if (this->inst()==assemble){
 10         movq    -176(%rbp), %rax        # this, tmp103
 11         movq    %rax, %rdi      # tmp103,
 12         call    _ZNK8function4instEv    #
 13         cmpl    $1, %eax        #, _1
 14         sete    %al     #, retval.0_23
 15         testb   %al, %al        # retval.0_23
 16         je      .L25    #,
 17 # function.cpp:19:              fr.cut=false;
 18         movq    -168(%rbp), %rax        # <retval>, tmp104
 19         movb    $0, (%rax)      #, fr_19(D)->cut
 20 # function.cpp:20:              fr.del[0]=m[0];
 21         movq    -168(%rbp), %rax        # <retval>, tmp105
 22         leaq    72(%rax), %rdx  #, _2
 23         movq    -184(%rbp), %rax        # m, tmp106
 24         movq    %rax, %rsi      # tmp106,
 25         movq    %rdx, %rdi      # _2,
 26 .LEHB0:
 27         call    _ZN8moleculeaSERKS_     #
 28 # function.cpp:21:              fr.del[1]=m[1];
 29         movq    -184(%rbp), %rax        # m, tmp107
 30         leaq    32(%rax), %rdx  #, _3
 31         movq    -168(%rbp), %rax        # <retval>, tmp108
 32         addq    $104, %rax      #, _4
 33         movq    %rdx, %rsi      # _3,
 34         movq    %rax, %rdi      # _4,
 35         call    _ZN8moleculeaSERKS_     #
 36 # function.cpp:22:              fr.add[0]=(this->id==0)? m[1]+m[0] : m[0]+m[1];
 37         movq    -176(%rbp), %rax        # this, tmp109
 38         movl    (%rax), %eax    # this_21(D)->id, _5
 39         testl   %eax, %eax      # _5
 40         jne     .L26    #,
 41 # function.cpp:22:              fr.add[0]=(this->id==0)? m[1]+m[0] : m[0]+m[1];
 42         movq    -184(%rbp), %rax        # m, tmp110
 43         leaq    32(%rax), %rcx  #, _6
 44         leaq    -160(%rbp), %rax        #, tmp111
 45         movq    -184(%rbp), %rdx        # m, tmp112
 46         movq    %rcx, %rsi      # _6,
 47         movq    %rax, %rdi      # tmp111,
 48         call    _ZNK8moleculeplERKS_@PLT        #
 49         jmp     .L27    #
 50 .L26:
 51 # function.cpp:22:              fr.add[0]=(this->id==0)? m[1]+m[0] : m[0]+m[1];
 52         movq    -184(%rbp), %rax        # m, tmp113
 53         leaq    32(%rax), %rdx  #, _7
 54         leaq    -160(%rbp), %rax        #, tmp114
 55         movq    -184(%rbp), %rcx        # m, tmp115
 56         movq    %rcx, %rsi      # tmp115,
 57         movq    %rax, %rdi      # tmp114,
 58         call    _ZNK8moleculeplERKS_@PLT        #
 59 .LEHE0:
 60 .L27:
 61 # function.cpp:22:              fr.add[0]=(this->id==0)? m[1]+m[0] : m[0]+m[1];
 62         movq    -168(%rbp), %rax        # <retval>, tmp116
 63         leaq    8(%rax), %rdx   #, _8
 64         leaq    -160(%rbp), %rax        #, tmp117
 65         movq    %rax, %rsi      # tmp117,
 66         movq    %rdx, %rdi      # _8,
 67         call    _ZN8moleculeaSEOS_      #
 68         leaq    -160(%rbp), %rax        #, tmp118
 69         movq    %rax, %rdi      # tmp118,
 70         call    _ZN8moleculeD1Ev        #
 71 # function.cpp:32:      return fr;
 72         jmp     .L24    #
 73 .L25:
 74 # function.cpp:25:              std::pair<molecule,molecule> p;
 75         leaq    -160(%rbp), %rax        #, tmp119
 76         movq    %rax, %rdi      # tmp119,
 77         call    _ZNSt4pairI8moleculeS0_EC1IS0_S0_Lb1EEEv        #
 78 # function.cpp:26:              p=m[0].split(this->id-2);
 79         movq    -176(%rbp), %rax        # this, tmp120
 80         movl    (%rax), %eax    # this_21(D)->id, _9
 81         leal    -2(%rax), %edx  #, _10
 82         leaq    -96(%rbp), %rax #, tmp121
 83         movq    -184(%rbp), %rcx        # m, tmp122
 84         movq    %rcx, %rsi      # tmp122,
 85         movq    %rax, %rdi      # tmp121,
 86 .LEHB1:
 87         call    _ZNK8molecule5splitEj@PLT       #
 88 # function.cpp:26:              p=m[0].split(this->id-2);
 89         leaq    -96(%rbp), %rdx #, tmp123
 90         leaq    -160(%rbp), %rax        #, tmp124
 91         movq    %rdx, %rsi      # tmp123,
 92         movq    %rax, %rdi      # tmp124,
 93         call    _ZNSt4pairI8moleculeS0_EaSEOS1_ #
 94         leaq    -96(%rbp), %rax #, tmp125
 95         movq    %rax, %rdi      # tmp125,
 96         call    _ZNSt4pairI8moleculeS0_ED1Ev    #
 97 # function.cpp:27:              fr.cut=true;
 98         movq    -168(%rbp), %rax        # <retval>, tmp126
 99         movb    $1, (%rax)      #, fr_19(D)->cut
100 # function.cpp:28:              fr.del[0] = m[0];
101         movq    -168(%rbp), %rax        # <retval>, tmp127
102         leaq    72(%rax), %rdx  #, _11
103         movq    -184(%rbp), %rax        # m, tmp128
104         movq    %rax, %rsi      # tmp128,
105         movq    %rdx, %rdi      # _11,
106         call    _ZN8moleculeaSERKS_     #
107 # function.cpp:29:              fr.add[0] = p.first;
108         movq    -168(%rbp), %rax        # <retval>, tmp129
109         leaq    8(%rax), %rdx   #, _12
110         leaq    -160(%rbp), %rax        #, tmp130
111         movq    %rax, %rsi      # tmp130,
112         movq    %rdx, %rdi      # _12,
113         call    _ZN8moleculeaSERKS_     #
114 # function.cpp:30:              fr.add[1] = p.second;
115         movq    -168(%rbp), %rax        # <retval>, tmp131
116         addq    $40, %rax       #, _13
117         leaq    -160(%rbp), %rdx        #, tmp132
118         addq    $32, %rdx       #, tmp133
119         movq    %rdx, %rsi      # tmp133,
120         movq    %rax, %rdi      # _13,
121         call    _ZN8moleculeaSERKS_     #
122 .LEHE1:
123 # function.cpp:25:              std::pair<molecule,molecule> p;
124         leaq    -160(%rbp), %rax        #, tmp134
125         movq    %rax, %rdi      # tmp134,
126         call    _ZNSt4pairI8moleculeS0_ED1Ev    #
127 # function.cpp:32:      return fr;
128         jmp     .L24    #
129 .L34:
130         movq    %rax, %rbx      #, tmp137
131 # function.cpp:25:              std::pair<molecule,molecule> p;
132         leaq    -160(%rbp), %rax        #, tmp135
133         movq    %rax, %rdi      # tmp135,
134         call    _ZNSt4pairI8moleculeS0_ED1Ev    #
135         jmp     .L31    #
136 .L33:
137         movq    %rax, %rbx      #, tmp136
138 .L31:
139         movq    -168(%rbp), %rax        # <retval>, tmp140
140         movq    %rax, %rdi      # tmp140,
141         call    _ZN14functionResultD1Ev #
142         movq    %rbx, %rax      # tmp136, D.69132
143         movq    %rax, %rdi      # D.69132,
144 .LEHB2:
145         call    _Unwind_Resume@PLT      #
146 .LEHE2:
147 .L24:
148 # function.cpp:33:      }
149         movq    -168(%rbp), %rax        # <retval>,
150         movq    -24(%rbp), %rbx # D.69134, tmp142
151         xorq    %fs:40, %rbx    #, tmp142
152         je      .L32    #,
153         call    __stack_chk_fail@PLT    #
154 .L32:
155         addq    $184, %rsp      #,
156         popq    %rbx    #
157         popq    %rbp    #
158         .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
159         ret
160         .cfi_endproc
```

I'am not an expert of assembly code, and I can't see where it goes wrong...

Comment: Did you compile with enabled optimization?

Comment: are you sure no exception is thrown from the function? difficult to tell more from the snippet you posted.

Comment: @mch I'm compiling with the -g and -gdb flags. Nor -Ox nor -Os

Comment: @Anders I am sure that no exceptions are thrown

Comment: A given address may in principle correspond to more than one source line and even more than one function, even at low optimisation levels. Try looking at the assembly. Are there any jumps into (or out of) the function body?

Comment: I'm curious, what C++ reference says to use `this->` to access the members?  You can access them directly.  You only need `this->` to resolve naming conflicts between method parameters and class members.

Comment: @n.m. not currently working on it, I'll check that

Comment: @ThomasMatthews It's just a matter of style. Some people use `m_id`, others `id_`, still others prefer `this->id`. I personally like neither style but I understand where this is coming from.